# In the excel/notepad, how to remove the row with single value?

Tags: excel

**The current input file is of below format**

```
20934 drinks.txt 

20934 latte.txt

20934 flatwhite.txt

20934 expresso.txt

20934

20935 drinks.txt 

20935 latte.txt

20935 flatwhite.txt

20935

20936 drinks.txt 

20936 latte.txt

20936 flatwhite.txt

20936
```

The requirement is to remove rows which has no second value

ie to remove row 20934  20935  20936  ..

since these rows have only 1 value. The end output should be like

```
20934 drinks.txt 

20934 latte.txt

20934 flatwhite.txt

20934 expresso.txt

20935 drinks.txt 

20935 latte.txt

20935 flatwhite.txt

20936 drinks.txt 

20936 latte.txt

20936 flatwhite.txt
```

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: No formula/vba required. Simply filter on `Text Filter - Contains` and use `Space` as the cirteria and then delete the selected rows?

Comment: The part `excel/notepad` is quite confusing. Please do clarify if you want to write the desired data from a text file to an `Excel` column range or from an `Excel` column range to a text file, or if you require something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that two fields are always separated by space. If you have Office 365 then you can use below formula:

`=FILTER(A1:A13,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",A1:A13,1)))`

If you do not have Office 365 then you can try below array formula which needs to be entered by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> simultaneously. If done correctly, Excel will wrap it with braces {}.

`=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",A:A,1)),ROW(A:A),10^15),ROWS($A$1:A1)))`

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked. What does 10^15 mean ?

Comment: @Amelia, it is a number which is larger than count of rows that Excel has. In principle one can easily use 10^7 in place of 10^15. After running out of valid data it will give error and thereby the stopping point. You can wrap it in IFERROR like `IFERROR(abovepostedformula,"")` if you don't want cells displaying errors.

Answer (score 1):

With <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd> you can try below `FILTER()` formula.

```
=FILTER(A:A,RIGHT(A:A,4)=".txt")
```

[image]

Comment: Even this solution worked seamlessly. I upvote this solution abut not cast the vote due to  few reputation :) Thank you